# manage.py runserver returns immediately

Tags: python, django

I have an existing django project which was working fine until I added a new app & models which makemigrations wouldn't detect.  As a newbie, I assumed the problem was that I'd missed a step somewhere.  So I decided to go back and do do the tutorial again to refresh my memory.  And now, I can't even get runserver to run properly

`python manage.py runserver`

just returns immediately with no output.  And this is on a project that consists only of the code django-admin startproject has generated.

I am at a loss how to work out where things are going wrong. I have had to reinstall my computer and am running python 3.6 and django 1.10.4, so maybe there's some system config issues somewhere.  This is a windows 7 environment running git bash and virtualenv, if that's relevant.

Any advice on how to proceed?

settings.py

"""
    Django settings for anewone project.

```
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@jy=4lr1(e0bl97*6un2-4tmfv%^k)ppoktw6m1o2%2myq7$j$'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'anewone.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'anewone.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

manage.py

## !/usr/bin/env python

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "anewone.settings")
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError:
        # The above import may fail for some other reason. Ensure that the
        # issue is really that Django is missing to avoid masking other
        # exceptions on Python 2.
        try:
            import django
        except ImportError:
            raise ImportError(
                "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            )
        raise
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: What happens if you just run `python` or just  `manage.py runserver` or try to run any other python file?

Comment: Could you please provide some of your code.

Comment: typing `python` gets me the python shell `./manage.py runserver` just hangs there no output

Comment: Kie, I haven't got as far as writing code yet, I'm just trying to run the autogenerated files!

Comment: What happens on `./manage.py shell`. Please post your settings and `manage.py` contents.

Comment: `./mange.py shell ` works ok and I can import django ok

Comment: there's an option `--traceback`, try to use it if that will help

Comment: just tried --traceback and still the same.  with python manage.py it just returns, with ./manage.py it hangs

Comment: Django 1.10 [does not support Python 3.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/faq/install/#faq-python-version-support), so try a clean install of Python 3.5 and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Doh! 3.5 has cleared most everything up.  At least I've moved beyond forgetting to put it on the path, maybe one day I'll learn how to rtfm!  Thanx for doing the homework I should have done knbk!